# Splash screen with circular progress bar

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, splash-screen, layer-list

I'm applying the splash screen as a style that is executed by AndroidManifest and is changed by main activity before loading the first layout. So the splash screen style loads the following layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:opacity="opaque"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/PrimaryDarkColor"/>

    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splash"
            android:id="@+id/splash"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

I would like to add an circular progress bar under the bitmap. I tried to follow differents tutorial but I don't have a xml where set progressbar before main activity starts.

Could you help me ?

Comment: Why cant you put it into a layout.xml and load that layout in onCreate

Comment: because when onCreate begins the splash screen disappears

Comment: Gotcha. What I do is have two activities. SplashScreenActivity with custom style AND layout with progressbar and MainAcitivity. SplashScreenActivity starts MainActivity when content is loaded.

Comment: Have to exist and elegant solution without creating another activity. I'll consider your solution. Thx

Comment: If you find a more elegant solution please post it!